# C# Программа не закрывается из-за потока

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Почему C# WPF программа не закрывается из-за потока в отдельном классе?

```
public class Model {
  protected ManualResetEventSlim slim;
  protected Thread _thread;
    public Model() {
      slim = new ManualResetEventSlim();
      this._thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadWork));
      this._thread.Start(slim);
    }

    private void ThreadWork(object obj) {
      ManualResetEventSlim s = (ManualResetEventSlim)obj;
      while(!s.IsSet) {
        s.Wait(1000);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пихать в конструктор запуск thread -- это что-то с чем-то.

Comment: @Bulson Почему?

Comment: Потому, что конструктор предназначен для создания объекта -- это его единственная задача. Хотите запускать еще, что-то, тем более асинхронное -- создайте отдельный метод и запускайте его после создания объекта. Посмотрите [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Snys7ursIg).

Comment: @Bulson, ok, на проблему это не влияет)

Comment: `Dispose()` - должен вызывать объект, который использует ваш `Model`, так что ищите проблему там

Comment: @Bulson, Dispose() работает, у меня закрывается главное WPF окно и собственно програма, разве не должен Thread уничтожиться вместе с программой?

Comment: В событие FormClosed вызовите метод Application.Exit();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В WinForms и WPF сделано так, что программа не завершается пока работают другие потоки. Если вам нужно чтобы он все таки останавливал эти потоки сам, то можно поставить флаг `IsBackground = true` у потока ([MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Thread_IsBackground)).

Comment: Правильней создать событие на закрытие программы в котором давать команду потоку сигнал на прекращение работы, например через `CancellationToken` и ждать остановки потока. Потому как если поток не сможет остановиться по какой либо причине, то вы об этом не узнаете.